# Matplotlib remove all patches from figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot various rectangles on top of an image stream. Before displaying the next image, all former rectangles should be removed again.

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21687571/matplotlib-remove-patches-from-figure) I found a first possible solution. Below is a simplified example of what I am doing at the moment.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
im = ax.imshow(np.zeros((800, 800, 3)))

for i in range(100):
    img = plt.imread('my_image_%03d.png' % i)
    im.set_data(img)

    rect_lst = getListOfRandomRects(n='random', dim=img.shape[0:2])
    patch_lst = [patches.Rectangle((r[0], r[1]), r[2], r[3],
                                   linewidth=1, facecolor='none')
                 for r in rect_lst]
    [ax.add_patch(p) for p in patch_lst]
    plt.pause(0.1)
    plt.draw()
    [p.remove() for p in patch_lst]
```

What I don't like about this is that I have to keep track of of the `patch_lst` in order to remove them again. I would prefer to simply remove all patches and get something like this:

```
for i in range(100):
    [...]

    rect_lst = getListOfRandomRects(n='random', dim=img.shape[0:2])
    [ax.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((r[0], r[1]), r[2], r[3],
                                    linewidth=1, facecolor='none'))
                 for r in rect_lst]

    plt.pause(0.1)
    plt.draw()
    ax.clear_all_patches()       # <-- this is what I am looking for
```

I did try `ax.clear()`, however this also removes the underlying image. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One possible way is to get a list of the patches using `ax.patches`. Therefore, you can use the existing list comprehension that you use to remove the patches using your list, but instead replace the list with `ax.patches()`:

```
for i in range(100):
    [...]

    rect_lst = getListOfRandomRects(n='random', dim=img.shape[0:2])
    [ax.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((r[0], r[1]), r[2], r[3],
                                    linewidth=1, facecolor='none'))
                 for r in rect_lst]

    plt.pause(0.1)
    plt.draw()
    [p.remove() for p in reversed(ax.patches)]
```

Comment: That does the job. Thank you =)

Comment: I should add that some rectangles are visible one or two loop iterations longer as expected. This can be solved by doing the list comprehension in reversed order. Otherwise it will stop before all elements are removed.

Answer (score 0):

This simple solution appears to work:

```
    ax.patches.clear()
```